# Ajax call return product list view

Tags: magento-1.9, module, local

Hello I am creating a module and I make a `ajax` call which from product list its return the template.

How can I do that?

For example I call to action `http:example.com/frontname/action/?id=x&search=hello`

And I want it return the block compiled. Is possible to make it?

```
Graphic example
```

[image]

On the ajax the php must generate the list products and return the html. The problem is I do not know how to load the bloack.

Comment: Which block you want in return ?

Comment: Means if you post : "hello" from Ajax, then you want template "hello.phtml" in return ?

Comment: the list of the products. But I do not know how is call

Comment: It means my producst name is Hello, but i have 5 products whic contains the word hello. I wan it return the list of these products but on the template

Comment: Yes it can be done. Can you share the screenshot of the page. So that we can get idea about scenario

Comment: Wait a minuts :D

Answer (score 0):

Through the Ajax call, POST the values to any function

Suppose you post the value "hello" to function "getProductList()"

then

in the function you can fetch the product list by following code

```
    function getProductList()
    {
        $productName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('//name of your field which contains product name', $productName);

    }
```

Comment: With that you are getting the collection I know how to do that. The thing I do not know is load de html and return the html

Comment: By default ajax returns the whole html contents of page, if any not particular value is printed. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586217/jquery-ajax-returns-the-whole-page

Comment: No return nothing